# Xpath expression to get paragraphs from rssfeed

Tags: c#, rss

http://lankacnews.com/sinhala/feed/

this is a feed address of a news web site. It contains 11 latest news.
I want to get those news from that rss feed and show them on my program. It contains news like this.

http://i44.tinypic.com/a3cxsw.png

between content : encoded tag.

I want to get it and show it in my application.
This is the code I have used..

```
XmlDocument lkcnws = new XmlDocument();
        lkcnws.Load(@"http://lankacnews.com/sinhala/feed/");

        textBox1.Text = lkcnws.OuterXml;

        XmlNodeList ndlst;
        XmlNode root = lkcnws.DocumentElement;

        ndlst = root.SelectNodes("//p");

        foreach (XmlNode nd in ndlst)
        {
            textBox2.Text += nd.OuterXml;
        }
```

but it does not work. Whats the wrong with this code and how can I solve this ?

Comment: do you get some exception? it does not work means a lot of things.

Comment: +No One No I didnt get any exception

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 void test() {
            XmlDocument lkcnws = new XmlDocument();

            lkcnws.Load("http://lankacnews.com/sinhala/feed/");

            textBox1.Text = lkcnws.OuterXml;

            XmlNodeList ndlst = lkcnws.SelectNodes("//category['@*']"); // it's null with p

            foreach (XmlNode nd in ndlst)
            {
                textBox2.Text += nd.InnerXml;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Xml.XmlNode' to 'System.Xml.XmlNodeList' C:\Users\Astro\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Lankadeepa\Lankadeepa\Form1.cs 54 25 Lankadeepa

Comment: :D Now I have to create a project and test your solution

Comment: I tried to get category node instead of <p>. It's working fine, but I don't understand it's null with <p>.

Comment: excuse me ? I dont get what you said .

Comment: Sorry for my English! I mean my code is working fine with "category" node. But it return null with "p" node. So make sure node "p" is exist. you see?

Comment: Actually p means <p> </p> tag.. Isnt it  a node ?

Comment: <content:encoded>
<![CDATA[
<p>රුසියාවට වඩා ඉහළ මිලිටරි බලයක්.</p>
]]>
</content:encoded>

Comment: +hicurin Yes I tried. It does not work :( and how to use "content:encoded" node ?

Comment: I mean with "//category['@*']" node. It works fine when I build the project. Textbox 2 give me the contents of this node

Comment: I tried. It gets the text between <category> </category> tags... But thats not what I want :(